# Getting a Bleach Bypass Look in the Compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

What nodes should I add and what should I change in compositor to get a good [bleach bypass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleach_bypass) film effect?
I would like to have a precise description of all nodes (for example, contrast-10).

[image: Example of the desired resault]

Comment: Could you add an example photo/video of what you want?

Comment: http://www.pixelphotoco.com/wp-content/uploads/Special-Effects-3.jpg -something like that. You know, i would like to make my video professional looking.

Comment: The way the question is currently phrased, it sounds a bit subjective to me. (what is "good"? what is "professional"?)

Comment: i show the photo, i would like to get the same effect

Answer (score 4):

The "bleach bypass look" can be replicated in its most simplest way by reducing saturation and increasing contrast of the image using bright/contrast node.

But instead to get a more detailed look what I would suggest is to:

1. have the image de-saturated slightly
2. have a copy of the original image de-saturated completely and boost
   the contrast of this layer by carefully using an RGB curves node
3. the monochrome layer should be mixed with the first image using
   "overlay" blending mode.

To adjust the contrast effect you would adjust the curve as desired and also the factor/strength of the mix/overlay node.

[image: example setup]

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4QTs.png)

In your example image the artist appears to have also used some sort of sharpening or detail enhancement to make details pop out more.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick attempt to get a similar effect to the reference image:

[image]
[full version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Ozm.png)

[image]