# How do I use render layers to give my model more light/dark contrast?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, light

I found some answers here that say you can make shadows darker with render layers, but I could not understand exactly what to do.  Mostly, I would like for my model to have more contrast (in cycles).  I currently am lighting it with 3 emission planes and everything looks right except the contrast needs to be increased. Moving the lights around and adding more lights just detracts.  Right now it is too soft-looking and needs more "ooomph" and perhaps there is some other way to add contrast without making it too hard-edged.  I also read about using a "light path" but I don't know where to start with that either!  Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: Probably you can go without using render layers for that. Did you try using [Bright/Contrast](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/color/bright_contrast.html) node or some other ones (or combining them) from [Color nodes](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/color/index.html) ?

Comment: I am not sure how to use Bright/Contrast nodes and other color nodes.  How and where do you plug them into the node tree?  Is there a good Youtube tutorial you can recommend?

Comment: related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/getting-a-bleach-bypass-look-in-the-compositor